# Is there a javascript command to postpone the video?

Tags: javascript, audio, video, youtube

So I am developing a javascript that allows you to postpone or pre-play audio so that it will sync with the video on Youtube.

I have solved the problem of postponing the audio, but I couldn't figure out a way to pre-play the audio.

I have a couple of ideas. To sync with the video,
I could either pre-play the audio or postpone the video. But I dont see any APIs that would let me do that.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: You mean something like go from min 0:13 to min 2:34 for example?

Comment: No. Like you have seen some videos and sound are not in sync. My goal is to make them in sync.

Comment: The way I solve the audio playing ahead is to live-capture the audio and play it 0.5 seconds later, this way the video is in sync with the audio.

Comment: But I dont know how to solve the problem of video playing ahead. I could either postpone the video or play the audio faster. But since it is live capture, I dont think I could play the audio faster. I tried to postpone the video, so the audio will catch up, but I couldnt see any APIs that would let me do that